# Elementary definition: what's a parallel volume-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, riemannian-geometry

This is a very elementary question,

What is the definition for a volume form (or $n$-form) to be parallel with respect to the metric? 
To find out more about the concept, what kind of topic do I need to look up in standard textbooks?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that $\nabla \omega = 0$, where $\omega$ is the volume form and $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection. See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9824/is-the-volume-form-on-an-oriented-riemannian-manifold-parallel) on math overflow.

Comment: what does $\nabla \omega$ mean?